# Static route to Single IP using SSL connection

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, ip, static-routes

I am trying to configure a static route to a single IP. My question is two fold:

1. How do I specify a single IP using a subnet mask `x.x.x.x/?` (not a range of ip's)
2. My pc is making an SSL connection to this ip. Can my router still look at the packet to see that the packets must be routed through my static route (Even though its connecting using ssl) ?

Scenario: I have a usenet client, and I want to forward all traffic downloaded from usenet, to go through a separate PPPOE account. I am having trouble specifying the destination of the usenet server, using IP/mask format. Even so, I am not sure if a router can forward (inspect) SSL traffic and re-route it?

I have tried a few different combinations of x.x.x.x/30  /31 , but I cant seem to direct the traffic onto my secondary pppoe account. It just sits idle, not showing any data flow. I have also tried the whole range, x.x.x.0/24 , but I also don;t seem to get any traffic on the interface.

- Router: Ubiquiti Edge Router Lite
- Usenet Server: ssl.hitnews.com (IP:
  81.171.92.192)
- Port: 563

Thanks

### UPDATE

When using the complete block of 81.171.92.0/24 , doing a trace route to 81.171.92.192, it shows that it is routing through the DSL ip of the 2nd pppoe account. This seem right, but my interface does not show the traffic (usage) of my usenet client.

### UPDATE

Ok using the whole 0/24 block, seems to work now (my ERL itnerface did not update properly). When I added the interface on the visual graph, it started showing some stats in the table below... (bug)?

I would still like to route using just the IP tho, and not the whole ip block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a slash notation mask of /32, implies one single host.

Thanks

```
Binary                             Hex        Quad Dec          2ⁿ    CIDR   Number of addresses

00000000000000000000000000000000   00000000   0.0.0.0           2³²   /0     4,294,967,296     4 G
10000000000000000000000000000000   80000000   128.0.0.0         2³¹   /1     2,147,483,648     2 G
11000000000000000000000000000000   C0000000   192.0.0.0         2³⁰   /2     1,073,741,824     1 G
11100000000000000000000000000000   E0000000   224.0.0.0         2²⁹   /3       536,870,912   512 M
11110000000000000000000000000000   F0000000   240.0.0.0         2²⁸   /4       268,435,456   256 M
11111000000000000000000000000000   F8000000   248.0.0.0         2²⁷   /5       134,217,728   128 M
11111100000000000000000000000000   FC000000   252.0.0.0         2²⁶   /6        67,108,864    64 M
11111110000000000000000000000000   FE000000   254.0.0.0         2²⁵   /7        33,554,432    32 M
11111111000000000000000000000000   FF000000   255.0.0.0         2²⁴   /8        16,777,216    16 M
11111111100000000000000000000000   FF800000   255.128.0.0       2²³   /9         8,388,608     8 M
11111111110000000000000000000000   FFC00000   255.192.0.0       2²²   /10        4,194,304     4 M
11111111111000000000000000000000   FFE00000   255.224.0.0       2²¹   /11        2,097,152     2 M
11111111111100000000000000000000   FFF00000   255.240.0.0       2²⁰   /12        1,048,576     1 M
11111111111110000000000000000000   FFF80000   255.248.0.0       2¹⁹   /13          524,288   512 k
11111111111111000000000000000000   FFFC0000   255.252.0.0       2¹⁸   /14          262,144   256 k
11111111111111100000000000000000   FFFE0000   255.254.0.0       2¹⁷   /15          131,072   128 k
11111111111111110000000000000000   FFFF0000   255.255.0.0       2¹⁶   /16           65,536    64 k
11111111111111111000000000000000   FFFF8000   255.255.128.0     2¹⁵   /17           32,768    32 k
11111111111111111100000000000000   FFFFC000   255.255.192.0     2¹⁴   /18           16,384    16 k
11111111111111111110000000000000   FFFFE000   255.255.224.0     2¹³   /19            8,192     8 k
11111111111111111111000000000000   FFFFF000   255.255.240.0     2¹²   /20            4,096     4 k
11111111111111111111100000000000   FFFFF800   255.255.248.0     2¹¹   /21            2,048     2 k
11111111111111111111110000000000   FFFFFC00   255.255.252.0     2¹⁰   /22            1,024     1 k
11111111111111111111111000000000   FFFFFE00   255.255.254.0     2⁹    /23              512
11111111111111111111111100000000   FFFFFF00   255.255.255.0     2⁸    /24              256
11111111111111111111111110000000   FFFFFF80   255.255.255.128   2⁷    /25              128
11111111111111111111111111000000   FFFFFFC0   255.255.255.192   2⁶    /26               64
11111111111111111111111111100000   FFFFFFE0   255.255.255.224   2⁵    /27               32
11111111111111111111111111110000   FFFFFFF0   255.255.255.240   2⁴    /28               16
11111111111111111111111111111000   FFFFFFF8   255.255.255.248   2³    /29                8
11111111111111111111111111111100   FFFFFFFC   255.255.255.252   2²    /30                4
11111111111111111111111111111110   FFFFFFFE   255.255.255.254   2¹    /31                2
11111111111111111111111111111111   FFFFFFFF   255.255.255.255   2⁰    /32                1
```